# Sublime Text 3: selects all typed text as you go along

Tags: macos, configuration, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 and I've suddenly started seeing this annoying bug where it selects all the text that was typed in it as you go along typing. I'm not sure if something I did had caused this.

The only package I have installed is 'Anaconda' for python.

All I changed was increase the font size. How do I fix this?

PS: I'm a new user so can't add images unless I have enough points.

Comment: Looks like the bug was caused by Anaconda package itself. Uninstalling the package did the trick.

Comment: This was a documented bug in Sublime Text 3.  Restarting the program usually does the trick for me.